# Is it possible to leverage of the all the power of the host in a single Hyper-V VM?

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I'm very new to virtualization and Hyper-V. I have a server with 2 quad core CPUs and 24 GB or RAM running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. I have a single VM also running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with the integration services installed.

Will I be able to leverage of the all the power of the host in a single VM? Right now I only see 4 processors in my VM's Task Manager. Do I need another version of Windows to see all 16 processors (2 cpu * 4 core * hyperthreading = 16)?

What are the best practices when running a single VM on a host?

Answer (score 2):

No. If for no other reason than, currently, a VM under Hyper-V is limited to 4 virtual cores and you have 16 on your host.

As a note  - next year with Hyper-V 3.0 this limit will be significantly higher (I think 32 processor cores).